# php checking validity of the format string provided for DateTime class

Tags: php, datetime

EventTime is a simple class that can return formatted timestamp of an event. This is my test cases class for EventTime

```
class EventTimeTest extends TestCase
{

    private $eventTime;
    private $dateTime;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->dateTime = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
        $this->eventTime = new EventTime($this->dateTime);
    }



    public function test_event_time_returns_a_valid_timestamp_when_format_is_given()
    {
        $this->assertEquals($this->dateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"), $this->eventTime->time("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"), "Event time should be a valid time");

    }

    public function test_event_time_throws_exception_when_format_is_not_valid()
    {
        $this->assertEquals($this->dateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"), $this->eventTime->time("some completely invalid format string provided with funny characters & smileys"), "Event time should be a valid time");

    }

}
```

and now this is my actual EventTime class that is being tested above

```
class EventTime implements EventTimeInterface
{
    private $timeStamp;

    public function __construct(\DateTime $time)
    {
        $this->timeStamp = $time;
    }

    public function time(string $format="Y-m-d H:i:s.u"): string
    {
        return $this->timeStamp->format($format);
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to handle the invalid format string case. If it is an emty string, that is an easy check, but what about strings like '11' or '¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥'. Does php have some builtin mechanism to throw an exception in such scenarios?

Comment: Why don't you try using those inputs and see what happens? Or read the docs on what PHP would return if you'd pass invalid parameters: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php, which uses https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Try using filters in php